# How to refresh an UpdatePanel without asyncpostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have a pop up which has formview and a save button. i want to refresh update panel when i click save button which is in pop up. How can i do this without asyncpostback? thanks for helps

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgSavePhoto" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/PhotoCompIcons/32x32/Document2.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Yeni Kayıt" />

        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeInsert" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgSavePhoto" CancelControlID="btnClose" PopupControlID="pnlModalPopup" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlModalPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                       <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="CloseButton">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/dialog_close.ico" ToolTip="Kapat" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="RecordType">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblRecordTypeName" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <asp:FormView ID="fvCompPartPhotos" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="odsCompPartPhotos" DefaultMode="Insert" EnableModelValidation="True" OnDataBound="fvCompPartPhotos_DataBound1" OnItemCommand="EditPhotoCommands" Style="margin-left: 0px">
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        //some codes
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                </asp:FormView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
          <div class="PhotoEditButtons">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgClear" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/PhotoCompIcons/32x32/Document2.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Yeni Kayıt" OnClick="imgClear_Click" />&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgSaveNew" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/PhotoCompIcons/32x32/Save.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Kaydet" OnClick="imgSaveNew_Click" />
 <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="fuPhoto" runat="server" />
                        </div>
```

Comment: Try using `Trigger`.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed you want to refresh the `UpdatePanel` without `asyncpostback`.

Here you go:-

***Solution***

```
YourUpdatePanelId.Update();
```

have a look here for [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx)

On `button click` you can set it easily

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LastUpdate.AddSeconds(5.0) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

You need to customize according to your requirement, that's it..!!!!

Comment: thanks a lot but i cant use asyncpostback. Asyncpostback doesnt help me because of my project

Comment: @rukenaslan: Is there any reason for that ??

Comment: yes. My pop up has asyncfileupload and it doesnt work with asyncpostback or i cant

Comment: @rukenaslan: See my `solution 2` for your answer